# Error when using chrome driver when attempting to execute python script

Tags: python, git, python-2.7, google-chrome, selenium

Having issue trying to automate when using python script.  I have access to repositories by GIT, where the python folders all use Python 2.7 syntax.  I also have chrome driver as well(Using ubuntu).  When I attempt to automate, I just get error, regarding python 2.7.  Unsure if thats the issue.

I was given a python code, that would use chrome driver to test if I can automate with the python code that is scripted for use once executed.  Using the command terminal, I get the following error:

```
traceback (most recent call last):
File "autotimesheet.py", line 254, in <module>
    processPDCI(res)
File "autotimesheet.py", line 85, in processPDCI
    driver = webdriver.Chrome('/home/myname/ChromeDriver')
File "/home/myname/.local/lib/python2.7/site-
       packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py", line 62, in __init__
self.service.start()
File "/home/myName/.local/lib/python2.7/site-
       packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 86, in start
os.path.basename(self.path), self.start_error_message)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'ChromeDriver' 
executable may have wrong permissions. Please see 
https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/home
```

So unsure how to solve it. Friend that is trying to help me is also stumped. I have use pip install selenium & pip install nose for set up. Unsure if I need to install anything else. So any guidance/help would be appreciated. Anything that is vague, I will try to provide better detail.  Hopefully this question is related to this section of stackoverflow. Thanks for reading

Comment: make sure you chrome driver binary belongs to same user & group that you ran program with

Comment: And that that user has read write and execute permissions for it

Comment: I'm assuming from the file path that you're on linux. Learning about file permissions is unfortunately pretty much mandatory. So you've got some reading ahead of you, but it's kinda hard to compress all of that into an SO answer.

Comment: Okay thanks for the comments! I will check the settings/path/R&W permission as well as just troubleshooting, and will update this topic later.

Answer (score 0):

just an update. I was able to automate the script.  Here was the only step I did:  In the autotimesheet.py, I change the line of code of this:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome('/home/myname/ChromeDriver/)
```

to:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome('/home/myname/ChromeDriver/chromedriver')
```

where the last part is the executable file.  So it opened up chrome and started to automate.  Now that I know this can automate, have to fix the issue with the repositories part.  With my .profile, I have this:

```
export SELENIUM_CHROME_DRIVER=/home/myname/ChromeDriver/chromedriver.exe
```

So either I have to fix this, or its another path/directory or r/w issue.  Thanks for the comments.  I will resolve in a few hours once I can get this fix!

*-----------UPDATE-----------*

Being able to fix the automation python script issue, I have to tackle the last issue.  I will still follow the comments, and will troubleshoot.  My error for future reference if anyone has similar problem:

ERROR: tests.test_to_run.TestsToRun.test_run_this_test

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/myName/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nose/case.py", line 197, in runTest
self.test(*self.arg)
File 
"/home/myname/Automation/pdci_keyword/python/tests/test_to_run.py", 
line 25, in test_run_this_test
self.test_controller.insert_steps_from_script_into_list_array()
 File 
 "/home/myName/Automation/pdci_keyword/python/lib/
web_interface/test_controller.py", line 337, in 
insert_steps_from_script_into_list_array
self.process_msg_insert(data)
 File 
"/home/myName/Automation/pdci_keyword/python/lib/web_interface/
test_controller.py", line 200, in process_msg_insert
```

Comment: Was able to automate correctly.  Lots of work though